# Loop para Valores únicos de columna en R

Tags: r, bucles, rstudio, pivot, tabla-dinámica

Quisiera pedir su ayuda con un tema. Tengo mi base de datos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En mi columna "Cliente", hay repetidos y estos hacen referencia a un año, semana, mes y ventas en particular. Quisiera hacer tal vez un bucle -no sé si esto sea la mejor forma-, para que primero me saque los únicos del vector "Cliente" y después, por ejemplo, sale "Nintendo", que considere solo los valores de ventas de "Nintendo", haga las demás instrucciones, lo guarde en una base y después, siga con el siguiente valor único del vector, que podría ser "Xbox" y lo mismo, que considere los valores de las ventas para esta nueva base o vector, considerando este segundo cliente y así hasta que se tengan todos los clientes.
Les agradecería mucho si me pudieran orientar, porque la verdad estoy en blanco.

Gracias!

Comment: Hola @Emilio. Bienvenido a **Stack Overflow**. Te invito realizar un [tour] para que conozca cómo funciona el sitio y gane tu primera medalla. Además, puede consultar [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que puedas aumentar tus posibilidades de obtener ayuda. También, puede consultar [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

Hola Emilio si entendí correctamente lo que deseas el el valor agrupado de ventas por cada uno de los clientes, voy a asumir que la la base de datos se llama videojuego y sobre so te comparto el código que te funcionaria

```
install.packages("dplyr")
library(dplyr)

resultado<-videojuegos %>% group_by(Cliente) %>%
                    summarise(Total=sum(ventas))
```

Esto funcionara correctamente si la variable venta es de tipo double o integer, ya que en el extracto de la base si apareciera como lo muestras en R con el signo de dinero , lo tomaría como string , lo que hace en pocas palabras el codigo es agrupar la suma de las ventas por Cliente. Es mas sencillo hacer esto que un ciclo for para ir sumando por cliente unico.

Comment: Hola @Ruben! me expliqué mal, y una disculpa. No busco hacer la sumatoria de las ventas por cliente. En la base tengo "n" clientes con sus respectivas ventas de cada uno. Lo que quiero hacer, es que tome cada uno de los clientes, considerando su frecuencia semanal y sus ventas; me lo transforme a series de tiempo y haga las pruebas pertinentes y la data resultante, me la almacene en un libro de Excel. Realmente necesito tratarlas como series de tiempo. Te agradezco mucho la ayuda, en verdad! Todo es con miras a poder hacer inferencia estadística

Comment: Ok, pero quieres probar si los datos son estacionarios ? o que tipo de análisis quieres realizar sobre la serie de tiempo?

Comment: Si, en un es ver si cumplen el supuesto de estacionariedad, porque quisiera hacer un forecast (para cada uno de los clientes en la misma rutina), con base en las ventas de cada uno.

Comment: @EmilioSaldaña me podrías ayudar a subir los datos como table y no como imagen, ya que esto me ayudaría a mostrarte un ejemplo de como transformarlo a una lineal de tiempo